# Beamer to HTML using make4ht

Tags: beamer, tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
aaa
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
bbb
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above tex file is to be converted into html. I am using the following command

```
make4ht filename.tex
```

However it throws error. The basic question is "Is it possible to convert beamer presentation to html using make4ht?"

Comment: An off-topic (but I think useful comment): `pandoc` is a powerful converter (at least for linux) that accepts `tex` files as input and output. It is not perfect ... But does a good job in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some support for Beamer in `tex4ht`, but it seems to be a little bit old - it is dated to 2003. It seems that it doesn't really work anymore, as Beamer changed substantially since that time. For example, it seems to support a `slide` environment instead of `frame`.

So it seems that we can just discard the current Beamer support and create a new one. Before it is added to the `tex4ht` sources, you can use the following `beamer.4ht` file:

```
\let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
\def\pgf@trimright@final{0pt}
\def\pgf@trimleft@final{0pt}
\let\origEndP\EndP
\AtBeginDocument{\def\EndP{\let\EndP\origEndP}\SaveEndP}
\endinput
```

It just fixes basic issues - spurious elements inserted for every page, some missing PGF commands and issues with paragraphs. This version will create just a plain document, without frames. If we want to keep the frames, we can configure them in a .cfg file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
   \ConfigureEnv{beamer@frameslide}
      {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
       \HCode{<section class="slide">}\RecallEndP\par\ShowPar
      }
      {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP \HCode{</section>}}
      {} {}
   \Css{section.slide {border:solid black 0.4pt;margin-bottom:1em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This will insert `<section class="slide">` element for every frame.

Result:

[image]

```xml
<section class="slide">


    <ul class="itemize1">
    <li class="itemize">
    first
    </li>
    <li class="itemize">
    second</li></ul>
<!--l. 16--><p class="noindent" >aaa


</p>
</section>


<section class="slide">


<!--l. 19--><p class="noindent" >bbb


</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I get framed frames, with the final contents, repeated for each slide of the frame. Frametitle shows with a color rectangle superimposed.

Comment: @vonbrand the Beamer support is quite old, so some things maybe don't work well as Beamer changes and old configurations may break. I worked on Beamer support last year, but didn't finish it. I can try to take a look again, if you have some example.