# MP4 in presentation in a non-broken way

Tags: beamer, html, media9, multimedia, video

I'm preparing a presentation using the beamer class and I want to add a mp4 video.
Unfortunately, everything I tried seems to be broken:

1. Try: Using the `\movie` command, `pdflatex` and okular: Doesn't work, because okular is buggy, sometimes plays the video too small.
2. Try: Using htlatex. htlatex is [broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482141/beamer-to-html-using-make4ht).
3. Try: Using `\movie`, building it using

```
latex $name
latex $name
dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1 -p1,- $name
```

and opening it using chromium. Chromium shows the slides, but won't play the video.

Is there a non broken way?

UPDATE:

With Alex G answer:

```
$ dvisvgm --exact --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --output=%f-%0p.svg main
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  graphic size: 455.24408pt x 256.074799pt (159.999995mm x 89.999998mm)
  output written to main-1.svg
1 of 4 pages converted in 0.343285 seconds
```

UPDATE:
This can be fixed using the `--page` argument.

But autoplay still won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a presentation in SVG format, you may give package `media4svg` a try.

Typeset with:

```bash
dvilualatex name
dvilualatex name
dvisvgm --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 --page=- --output=%f-%0p.svg name
```

and open `name-1.svg` in the (Chrome, Firefox, ...) browser.

---

Here is the example ([source](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg/example/beamer-example.tex)) that comes with the package (Click to see it in action):

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{media4svg}
\usepackage{menukeys,siunitx,calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols <--, -->
% mouse cursor autohide on idle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\def\navBtnSize{9pt}
\def\navBtnLnWd{1.6pt}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <style>svg{cursor: none}</style>%
      <defs>%
      <script type="text/javascript">%
      <![CDATA[%
        var svgRoot=document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];%
        var cursorTimer;%
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){%
           e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();%
           svgRoot.style.cursor='initial';%
           if(e.target!=svgRoot){%
             e.target.style.cursor='inherit';%
           }%  
           try{clearTimeout(cursorTimer);}catch(err){};%
           cursorTimer=setTimeout(function(){e.target.style.cursor='none';},3000);%
        });%
        document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){%
          if(e.key=='PageDown'||e.key=='ArrowDown'||e.key=='ArrowRight'){%
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'||e.key=='ArrowUp'||e.key=='ArrowLeft'){%
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }%
        });%
      ]]>%
      </script>%
      </defs>%
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Presentation example with embedded video}
\subtitle{Use a Web browser and press \keys{F11}}
\author{AlexG}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{british}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\titlepage\footnotesize
\makebox[0.3\linewidth]{\hrulefill}\\[1ex]
Navigate with \keys{PageUp} \& \keys{PageDn}, toggle Full-Screen with \keys{F11}.\\[2ex]
To build this presentation from the source, run:\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{verbatim}
dvilualatex beamer-example
dvilualatex beamer-example
dvisvgm --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 --page=- --output=%f-%0p.svg \
                                                                     beamer-example
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Video file}
  Embedded local video file from package \emph{mwe}
\begin{verbatim}
\includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em]{}{example-movie.mp4}
\end{verbatim}
  \begin{center}
  \includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em]{}{example-movie.mp4}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Remote video}
  Video streamed from URL
\begin{verbatim}
\includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em,url]{}{%
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm}
\end{verbatim}
  \begin{center}
    \includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em,url]{}{https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Player control}

The standard player controls (option `\verb+controls+') take a lot of space of the media display. Therefore, it is not recommended to enable them. Nevertheless, interactivity is still provided through touch or left mouse button click, and through the keyboard as summarized in the table.

Click on the media display to start playback. To pause playback, press the left mouse button on the media display. Release it to resume playback. To pause playback permanently, press the left mouse button on the media display and move the mouse out while keeping the button pressed.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \rule{1ex}{0pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
  Command & Shortcut\\\hline
  \rule{0pt}{2.4ex}Toggle Play/Pause & \keys{\SPACE}\\
  Increase volume & \keys{\arrowkeyup}\\
  Decrease volume & \keys{\arrowkeydown}\\
  Unmute audio & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyup}\\
  Mute audio & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeydown}\\
  Toggle Full-Screen & \keys{F11}
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \rule{1ex}{0pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
  Command & Shortcut\\\hline
  \rule{0pt}{2.4ex}Seek back \SI{1}{\percent} & \makebox[\widthof{\keys{\SPACE}}][l]{\keys{\arrowkeyleft}}\\
  Seek forward \SI{1}{\percent} & \keys{\arrowkeyright}\\
  Seek back \SI{10}{\percent} & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyleft}\\
  Seek forward \SI{10}{\percent} & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyright}\\
  Seek to beginning & \keys{Home}\\
  Seek to end & \keys{End}
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Note:** For having a video auto-play on page-open, it must be muted at the same time. This is for security reasons. Thus, `,autoplay,muted` must be added to the option list of `\includemedia...`. (See `texdoc media4svg`.)

Comment: On my machine, this creates main-1.svg but not main-2.svg

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include `-p-` option. (See edit.)

Comment: @VolkerWeißmann Does the example work for you if you re-build it on your own?

Comment: Yes, but I need autoplay/autostart and that won't work.

Comment: @Volker For security reasons, Web browsers ignore the autoplay setting if the video is not explicitly muted at the same time. See `texdoc media4svg`, So you need to add `,autoplay,muted` to the option list of \includemedia...

Comment: Thank you , this seems to work.

Comment: One thing is still bad: While the video is playing, you cannot use the pageup/down keys to change the slide without clicking above the video first. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your code breaks if you add `\usetheme{metropolis}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123631/discussion-between-alexg-and-volker-weissmann).

Comment: @VolkerWeißmann : This is because the video has the focus. First click Tab, then PgUp or PgDown.

Comment: @VolkerWeißmann With the updated `media4svg` (v. 0.7, 2022/05/18), page up/down works immediately, even if the video has the focus.