# Can LaTeX create a rolling PDF to subtitle a video?

Tags: pdftex

A number of educational applications require a video to have a subtitle. Can LaTeX create a timed-text rolling PDF for this purpose?

Here is how a video on MIT site looks like. My question is how to do the subtitling with a PDFLaTeX file. Note that the sentence that is being spoken is highlighted and the rest of subtitled text is below or above it. The text scrolls in sync with the video. So there need to be time tags in the latex file to be synchronized with the video.

[image]

Examples of video embedding in LaTeX is given by
[Alex G.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595102/mp4-in-presentation-in-a-non-broken-way)

Comment: That would depend on the applicaton showing the video and scrolling the text.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  Do you have a link or sample file etc.