# Beamer video working in presentation and normal mode

Tags: beamer, animate, media9, multimedia

As many LaTeX users, I know that including a video in a Beamer PDF is a pain.
The Internet is saying that easy, but I still got troubles with it (codec maze, etc).

In the past, I succeeded to include (and play) a video both on Linux (using `multimedia`) and Windows (using `media9`).
(OK, now it cannot reproduce this achievement since, AcrobatReader on Windows is no longer supporting Flash).
However, with these 2 solutions, videos are not really embedded in the PDF, only displayed inside thanks to readers.
To test this last assertion, after compilation, I change the location of my videos.
And, as expected, the PDF is no longer able to play them.

An alternative, is to split videos into images, and ask Beamer to `animate` these images into a video.
This option as the advantage to embed the videos and it is supposed to be Linux-Windows-friendly (not tested on Windows yet).

Now, I would like to go to the next level.
I would like to extend the working area of these methods.
Indeed, the `multimedia` approach is working in the "presentation" mode, but not in the "normal" mode of my PDF viewer.
While, the `animate` method is working in the "normal" mode but not in the "presentation" mode.
Since there is no intersection area, if I have a presentation that uses a combination of these 2 methods, I have to enter and exit "presentation" mode all the time... Super annoying and messy.

Thus, I would like to know if it is possible to play an `animate` video in "presenation" mode and/or play a `multimedia` video in "normal" mode ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeWarsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multimedia} % for linux
\usepackage{media9} % for windows
\usepackage{animate} % for both ?


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Option A: linux only}
        \movie[ % On linux with okular ++ poppler and phonon-backend-vlc installed
            showcontrols=true, %
            width=0.8\linewidth
        ]%
        {\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,draft]{./movie_snap.png}}
        {./movie.avi}% or .mp4
        
        With this option:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item I need to accept the "interactive forms",
            \item I \textbf{cannot} play the video in "normal" mode: when I click nothing moves.
            \item I can play the video in "presentation" mode.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Option B: windows only}
        \includemedia[% % Windows AcrobatReader >9.1
            activate=pagevisible,%
            deactivate=pageclose,%
            addresource=./movie.mp4,%
            flashvars={%
                src=./movie.mp4 % same path as in addresource !
                &autoPlay=true % 
                &loop=true % 
                &controlBarAutoHideTimeout=0 %
            },%
            width=0.8\linewidth %
            ]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,draft]{./movie_snap.png}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
        
        With this option:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Is not working anymore, since Flash is no longer supported.
            \item Any \textbf{replacement} ? 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Option C: linux and windows}
        % \animategraphics[<options>]{<frame rate>}{<file basename>}{<first>}{<last>}
        \animategraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,controls]{10}{./movie-}{001}{099}%.png
        
        With this option:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item I need to accept the "interactive forms",
            \item I can play the video in "normal" mode.
            \item I \textbf{cannot} play the video in "presentation" mode: when I click on the control, it goes to the next slide.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could instead produce presentations in SVG format and use `animate` and `media4svg` packages. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595106

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for your comment. Indeed, it is an interesting workaround, even if it not perfectly fitting to the original question.

Comment: Web browsers (Firefox, Chrome) can be set to Full Screen (presentation mode) and back to "normal mode" with [F11] on the keyboard. Videos and animations run in both modes.

Comment: Yes, this is why I truly like your comment and the associated references. (You can turn it into an answer I will at least upvote). It would be great if we could to the same with PDF (my co-workers know only PDF or PPT)...